# Wordpress Redirect After logging

Tags: login, wp-redirect

The following code below allows to me authenticate user against a custom table I created:

```
 function authentication($emailAdd, $password) {
            include_once('././wp-includes/class-phpass.php');

        global $wpdb, $formErr;

        if(1 > count($formErr->get_error_messages())){
            $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);

            $table = $wpdb->prefix.'finusers';
            $results=$wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE email_address='$emailAdd'");
            $hashed_pwd = $results->password;
            //echo $hashed_pwd;

            if($hasher->CheckPassword($password, $hashed_pwd)){

                //redirection has to happen here

            }else{
                echo "Please check email address of password";
            }
        }
 }
```

My question is how can I redirect users to a specific page?

Comment: When is that `authentication` function called? And why do you use custom table? (and don't use any SQL escaping, and don't check any errors, and so on...)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your function is called before any output is printed - otherwise redirection won't work.

The easiest way to redirect user to given URL is using:

```
wp_redirect( $url );
exit;
```

So your code might look like this:

```
function authentication($emailAdd, $password) {
            include_once('././wp-includes/class-phpass.php');

        global $wpdb, $formErr;

        if(1 > count($formErr->get_error_messages())){
            $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);

            $table = $wpdb->prefix.'finusers';
            $results=$wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE email_address='$emailAdd'");
            $hashed_pwd = $results->password;
            //echo $hashed_pwd;

            if($hasher->CheckPassword($password, $hashed_pwd)){

                wp_redirect( $url );  // change to correct URL
                exit;

            }else{
                echo "Please check email address of password";
            }
        }
 }
```

PS. There are a lot of errors and problems with your code, though... And I really wouldn't use that on any site, I guess... At least not in current form... See my comments in code below

```
function authentication($emailAdd, $password) {
        // using ././ won't work. It should be ../../. And even that is risky, because the structure may be changed - you should use ABSPATH instead.
        include_once('././wp-includes/class-phpass.php');

        global $wpdb, $formErr;

        // so if there is exactly one error, everything is fine and user can be logged in? ;)
        if(1 > count($formErr->get_error_messages())){
            $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);

            $table = $wpdb->prefix.'finusers';
            // Why no escaping? What if $emailAdd will contain special characters to perform SQL injection?
            // Another problem is that you query all rows, why no limit?
            $results=$wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE email_address='$emailAdd'");
            // And what if there are no such rows? Line below will cause error
            $hashed_pwd = $results->password;
            //echo $hashed_pwd;

            if($hasher->CheckPassword($password, $hashed_pwd)){

                wp_redirect( $url );  // change to correct URL
                exit;

            }else{
                echo "Please check email address of password";
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: @Drozdz, the code is still in development, wouldn't be pushing it into production as yet. The code above only shows part of my project. There is function in my code that takes care of sanitizing and escaping before its passed on to the code above. I read your comments and will look into the suggestions you made.

Comment: @MetalZer0 and still, you have a function that takes data and uses it in insecure manner. It's always a bad idea to do it in such way - after a while you won't remember about it and use it in such way, that SQL injection will happen ;)

Comment: @Drozdz, most what I am doing comes from the wordpress codex. I broken up most of my code into functions, one that handle data validation, sanitizing and escaping or characters and authentication.

Comment: @Drozdz, for sql injection I read about prepared statements on the wordpress codex. but what would you recommend?

Comment: @MetalZer0 codex is only documenting functions. It doesn't teach you how to construct your functions or how to process errors in proper way. And clearly - your code ignores a lot of edge cases... But of course you may assume that you know better and there is no problem with it. As for SQL Injection - I would recommend to protect your code agains it and use prepared statements.

Comment: @Drozdz, I kindly ask if you could list some of the edge cases that my code ignores so that I may look it. I have limited exposure to wordpress and would like a starting base to look into to get a better understanding of wordpress

Comment: @MetalZer0 it's off-topic for this question, so I don't want to spend a lot of time for this discussion... Edge cases are already in my answer - you ignore case, when no results are found. You ignore the case, when there are malicious characters in email. You let user register even, if there was an error in your form. You ignore the case, when $formErr is not initiated. You hardcoded path to wp-includes...